# Using boost::hana to check for method existence

Tags: c++, boost, boost-hana

I'm trying to create a templated function `contains` that works for any container by trying these two steps:

- Using the container's own find method `.find(value)` if it exists (which should be optimized for that specific container)
- Using `std::find(xs.cbegin(), xs.cend(), v)` as a fallback

It seems that boost::hana provides an `is_valid` or a `sfinae` function to check for that, but I wasn't able to figure out how they work...

```
template<typename TContainer, typename T>
bool
contains(
    const T &v,
    const TContainer &container)
{
    constexpr auto has_find = boost::hana::is_valid([](auto &&xs, auto &&x) -> decltype((void)xs.find(x)) {});

    if constexpr(has_find) {
        return container.find(v) != container.cend();
    } else {
        return std::find(container.cbegin(), container.cend(), v) != container.cend();
    }
}
```

Comment: Should it `if constexpr(decltype(has_find(container, v)){})`?

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly (I even simplified it into `if constexpr(has_find(container, v))`)!
For some reason, I already tried doing something similar to `constexpr auto has_find = is_valid(...)(container, v)` but it did not work and I didn't explored it further...